# Conditional @click with a method in vuejs

Tags: if-statement, vue.js

This is my for loop:

```
  <li v-for="(crumb, index) in breadcrumbs" :class="{ 'is-active' : index==breadcrumbs.length-1 }">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-if="index==breadcrumbs.length-1">{{ crumb.name }}</a>
  </li>
```

@click="methodName" shouldn't be available for the last iteration.

I can check the last iteration with index==breadcrumbs.length-1
Is this possible using apply v-if?

Comment: Just bind the `@click` handler as usual, but in the callback simply check if the item is the last item. If it is the last item, return false or just do `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 39):

There is a possibility by defining the event handler this way:

```
v-on="condition ? { eventName: () => handler } : {}"
```

The ?: operator can be used as a shortcut for an if...else statement

In your case it would be like this:

```
<li v-for="(crumb, index) in breadcrumbs" :class="{ 'is-active' : index==breadcrumbs.length-1 }">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" v-on="index < breadcrumbs.length-1 ? { click: () => methodName(parms) } : {click: ($event) => $event.preventDefault() }" >{{ crumb.name }}</a>
</li>
```

[Small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w6m9jgb/)

Answer (score 1):

```
@click="someBooleanVariable ? console.log('yes') : {}"
```