# Vuejs: Call a function on @click conditionally

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button named continue, what I want to do is on clicking I want to check a condition if `isUpgrade` is true or not. If its true it has to execute `proceedToPayment = true` and if its false the other one `validateSite()` - (need to call a method).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click="isUpgrade ? proceedToPayment = true : validateSite()">Continue</button>
```

The above code is not working. Is this really possible? If it is where have I got it wrong?

I have referred to this Stack Overflow Question - [Conditional @click with a method in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742525/conditional-click-with-a-method-in-vuejs)
but I'am not really getting the answer to it.

Comment: Err, why are you ternary true/false cases strings and not expressions?  Remove the single quotes around your assignment expression and your method call expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need single quotes:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click="isUpgrade ? {proceedToPayment = true} : { validateSite() }">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Missed that

Answer (score 2):

You can just take away the quotation marks in the ternary:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isUpgrade: false,
    proceedToPayment: false
  },
  methods: {
    validateSite() {
      console.log('working')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click="isUpgrade ? proceedToPayment = true : validateSite()">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With single quotes you have a string. Remove the quotes and it should work like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isUpgrade: true,
    proceedToPayment: false
  },
  methods: {
    validateSite: function() {
      alert('validateSite called!');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click="isUpgrade ? proceedToPayment = true : validateSite()">Continue</button>

  {{ proceedToPayment }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Missed that